# Configuring Rolling File Appender

Tags: jboss, log4j

My jboss application server log file named jboss-log4j.xml has the following configuration for the rolling file appender

```
<appender name="FILE" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.RollingFileAppender">
 <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
 <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/server.log"/>
 <param name="Append" value="false"/>
 <param name="MaxFileSize" value="500KB"/>
 <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="1"/>

 <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
 </layout>      
</appender>
```

What does this exactly do ?
How should I set it to do either of the two things ?
1. Delete logs older than 5 days or
2. Delete logs when they exceed 800MB, so that once they are deleted the new logs can take effect

Comment: You've now asked 3 near-identical questions in a row. Please don't do that.

Comment: Yes I did it because I am not getting the right answer and after scouring the web I am unable to find a tutorial for the same
Can you point me out to a tutorial that explains stuff to me

Comment: If you are not getting the right answer, maybe you did not ask the right question?... it is much better to go back and update/ refine your question than to post a similar new one (and blame the people who took the effort to try and help you).

Answer (score 3):

Most of the parameters are explained in the manual I linked to your earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559804/rolling-file-appender-usage/2559879#2559879). Even if that shows the parameters in a property file, the name and semantics of the parameters is the same.

AFAIK you can't easily make a log file roll over every 5 days. The closest to this is weekly rollover. For this you should use a `DailyRollingFileAppender` as I showed in my previous answer, and set its date pattern to

```
<param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-ww"/>
```

See the usage options of `DailyRollingFileAppender` [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html).

Setting the size limit of the `RollingFileAppender` shown in your post to 800MB instead of 500KB is a task I am sure you can resolve yourself ;-)

So you can easily have a log file rolling over *either* at the start of every week *or* upon reaching a specified size limit. However, I have a vague recollection that the two don't go together. You either have a `DailyRollingFileAppender` or a `RollingFileAppender` - Log4J doesn't provide an appender with *both* functionality at the same time. Neither to roll over your log file every 5 days - your only option to achieve this is to implement your own custom appender.

Answer (score 1):

You ask how to delete logs older than 5 days. Typically, we will setup a cron job that uses find to delete old log files and zip files that are not quite as old. For example:

```
find /apps/atg/$JBOSS_VERSION/jboss-as/server/${inst_name}/log \
  -name "*.log.2*" -type f -mtime +14 -exec rm {} \;
find /apps/atg/$JBOSS_VERSION/jboss-as/server/${inst_name}/log \
  -name "*.log.2*" ! -name "*.gz" -type f -mtime +3 -exec gzip {} \;
```